# how to change code below from mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

In mysql I have this code below:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$dbactive = $row['active'];

if ($dbactive == 1){

...

}...
```

But I have to use mysqli in my project. So I have tried changing it below but I am not quite getting it right. Can anyone just help me correct the below statement in mysqli so it matches the mysql's statement above?

UPDATE:

My attempt in mysqli:

```
   // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
        $query = "SELECT TeacherForename, TeacherSurname, TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword, Active FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ? AND TeacherPassword = ? LIMIT 1";
        // prepare query
        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
        // You only need to call bind_param once
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$teacherusername,$teacherpassword);
        // execute query
        $stmt->execute(); 
        // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
        $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherForename,$dbTeacherSurname,$dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword, $dbActive);

            while($stmt->fetch()) {

      if ($teacherusername == $dbTeacherUsername && $teacherpassword == $dbTeacherPassword) {
   if ($dbActive == 1){

        $loggedIn = true;
}
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only returning one row, you don't need a `while` loop. `bind_result()` takes `x` columns and assigns their values, in order, to the variables you pass in. So, assuming that your result only contains one row with one column, `bind_result($dbactive)` would be the same as `$dbactive = $row['active']` with `mysql_*`.

Comment: I have updated code, I have not tested it but do you think the code above is correct or will it still cause a problem?

Comment: @user1517628 You don't need the second `bind_result()`. You already bind the result to `$dbactive` in the first call with multiple variables passed.

Comment: Sorry the second bind result was me being careless and forgetting to remove it from the code before the update. I will test it and see what happens :)

Comment: Becuase you helped me in both questons, I am giving you best answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Binding a variable means the result row value will be automatically placed into that varaible whenever you call ->fetch(). You're trashing that binding with your

```
$dbactive = $stmt['active'];
```

$stmt is a result object, not a row object or array. It would not have any of the data you've pulled up via the query.

Comment: I have updated code, I have not tested it but do you think the code above is correct or will it still cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the query method,

```
$result = $myslqi->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
  $row->active …
}
```

Comment: I have updated code, I have not tested it but do you think the code above is correct or will it still cause a problem?

Comment: You're duplicating the username/password check. If the provided u/p don't match, then your query would return 0 rows. There's no pointing in having MySQL comparing u/p, then having PHP do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching a single row you can use:

```
if($query = $db->prepare("your sql query where field1=? AND field2=?")){

    $query->bind_param('ss', $user_id); 
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($field1, $field2);
    $query->fetch();
    echo $field1;

}
```